# Lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two functions, A and B:

```
def A():
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]
    while some_condition(my_list):
        # ... (make changes to my_list)
    solution = B(my_list)

def B(my_list):
    my_list.append(4)
    # ... (find a solution)
    return solution
```

I have a list in my function A. I want to pass this list as a argument to function B. Function B makes changes to it to get an answer, but I do not want the changes made to the list in function B to reflect on the list in function A, since I wish to find multiple answers using the same list. What is the best possible way to isolate changes made in function B from function A?

Comment: Please provide code so we don't chase our tails asking dozens of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to pass a copy of the list to `B`:

```
def A():
    ...
    B(list(mylist))  # shallow copy of mylist
    ...
```

This should be fine if you're not planning on mutating the elements contained within the list (but rather just mutating the list itself). If this isn't the case, you might want to create a deep copy using [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

From your edit, it looks like the list is a list of integers. Since integers are immutable, you can use the first approach without any problems: `B(list(mylist))`.

**Note** that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since that's already the name of a built-in function. I've used "`mylist`" above instead.